# how to detect Blank value in python?

Tags: python, detection

How to detect or check of blank value in all features and visualize it?

(Data Exploration) 
another question: if the dataset does not contain blank values, 
what is the result?

```
# Missing Or balnk values 
featurelist = []
count_of_blank_list = []

for col in dataset:
      cnt == ""
for i in dataset[col]:
    if i== "":
        cnt = cnt + 1
if col!='Class lable':
    #print (col, "-", cnt)
    featurelist.append(col)
    count_of_blank_list.append(cnt)

objects = tuple(featurelist)
y_pos = np.arange(len(featurelist))
performance = count_of_blank_list

fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]

# Set figure width to 12 and height to 9
fig_size[0] = 11
fig_size[1] = 3

plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', color='b', alpha=0.9)
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)

plt.ylabel('Count of blank values')
plt.title('Count of blank values per feature')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

`NameError: name 'cnt' is not defined`

Comment: do you mean ```None``` when you say blank?

Comment: @griffin_cosgrove, yes (None or Space)

Comment: `cnt` should be initialized to 0, as it is later treated as an integer

Comment: To test a variable `item` for the conditions "None", "empty string" or "all-blank string" you could use  `isblank = not (item or "").strip()`.   The `item or ""` part deals with the possibility of `item == None` before doing the string strip.

Comment: Note the line `cnt == ""` doesn't do anything, except throw a NameError (without initializing `cnt` beforehand)

Comment: @AbbeGijly, thx for the help, if I delete one (=), maybe the code is run, but now I want to apply it on a dataset that contains blank values!